# Is there any subclass of monk related to fire?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, archetype

My DM has started a new campaign based around a volcano, and I want to play a monk that believes fire is God. Is there any sort of subclass or archetype of monk (not way of four elements) related to fire? If not, what's the closest one or even alternative classes?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not four elements? Seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: The lore of my character is that they shun all other elements, so it wouldn't fit very well.

Comment: One thing worth considering, separate to this question, is that prepping a character to do lots of fire *damage* may be suboptimal if the campaign will pit you against many fire-based creatures who are likely to have resistance or immunity. A monk can usually fall back to at least half-decent unarmed attacks though, so you are probably fine provided it is not every encounter.

Comment: @TheDragonOfFlame [Please do not answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### The Way of the Sun Soul

Originally published in *Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide*, and republished in *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*, the Way of the Sun Soul is probably the most on-brand for a monk of fire. From the SCAG:

> ##### The Sun Souls
>
> The Sun Soul monks follow a monastic tradition that they believe has its roots in the ancient empire of Netheril. In their philosophy, living things harbor a fragment of the sun’s mystic essence within them. Just as the body has a shadow, so too does the spirit have a light. That light is called the sun soul. Brothers and sisters of the Order of the Sun Soul train to tap into the “spiritual light within” and manifest it as supernatural feats of prowess and endurance.

One of the features gives the ability to cast *burning hands* as a bonus action, and the rest enhance your attacks with radiant damage in various ways (no reason you couldn’t change radiant to fire, just ask your DM).

#### The Way of the Ascendent Dragon

The Way of the Ascendent Dragon from *Fizban’s Treasury of Dragons* gives you a choice of a few damage types to use with its features. This could easily be flavored as a fire monk by selecting fire and theming your character around a red dragon.

Comment: Way of the Ascendent Dragon is an alternative...just focus on doing fire damage instead of the other elemental options.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, anything related to dragons is outlawed in this world.

Comment: @Lamentix you're free to reflavour the abilities in that subclass with advice from your DM 

Comment: Way of the Ascendent Fire-Breathing Entity

Answer (score 8):

## Way of the Four Elements (but only pick disciplines related to fire).

This is posted specifically in response to the OP’s comment regarding the Way of the Four Elements that:

> The lore of my character is that they shun all other elements, so it wouldn't fit very well.

I contend that this is a false premise. The name makes it sound balanced across all the elements, but in reality it actually doesn’t really work that way unless you want to diversify your build, and an elementally diversified Way of the Four Elements Monk is usually suboptimal (the subclass as a whole is arguably sub-optimal since they can’t either of the good elemental damage types (acid and electricity), but not focusing a build tends to leave you kind of weak).

The lore for the subclass also fits to some extent, as it actually states that elemental specialists *do* exist within the tradition, which means that while the name doesn’t fit, the tradition itself does. And, TBH, the name is the easiest thing to change in-universe (the character could easily be from a group of monks in the setting that call themselves something like the Fire Fists or Flame Souls and entirely consists of fire-focused WotFE Monks, rebranding things in character is not hard).

As far as the actual build, you get an off-brand Prestidigitation that functionally ties in to the elemental aspect, plus access to a total of four out of 17 special abilities, most of which let you spend ki points to cast a spell.

A fire focused build would involve picking:

- Fangs of the Fire Snake: Spend a ki point to convert unarmed strikes to fire damage and extend their reach by 10 feet, lasts a turn. Additionally option to burn extra ki points per hit on such a turn to deal bonus fire damage.
- Sweeping Cinder Strike: Spend 2 ki points to cast Burning Hands
- Flames of the Phoenix: Spend 4 ki points to cast Fireball
- River of Hungry Flame: Spend 5 ki points to cast Wall of Fire

The only reference in such a build to elements other than fire would be in the Elemental Attunement ability, which you can just choose to only use in ways that relate to fire.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this fire-focused build suboptimal for the monk? I know lots of folks think the four elements monk is already suboptimal, so any further reduction would be a concern here if you're recommending it.

Comment: @NautArch Probably, but that’s not specific to the WotFE approach. Fire is the easiest non-physical damage type to get, but it’s also the one with the most creatures with immunity or resistance (closely followed by cold and then thunder). In some campaigns (Descent into Avernus for example), a fire-focused build i going to be close to useless no matter what class or subclass is involved, but even when it isn’t it’s often the least useful option.

Comment: You can re-flavour some other 4-elements abilities to be fire themed instead of water themed.  For example, [Fy'ra Rai](https://criticalrole.fandom.com/wiki/Fy%27ra_Rai) did this successfully on ExU (Fire Genasi 4-elements monk; her Water Whip was Lava Whip, still mechanically the same doing bludgeoning damage.)  You could similarly re-skin some other abilities like Clench of the North Wind (hold person) to be some fire-based immobilizer, like call it Burning Chains or something.  The ones that do elemental damage of another type are less easy, but you could allow a different spell.

Comment: e.g. you could allow Wall of Fire instead of Wall of Stone, and maybe swap the cone of cold ability for a cone of fire (same dice as the spell, dex save instead of con).  Ride the Wind (Fly) could easily be some kind of flame jet propulsion (or for less silly, just something about how fire rises into the air).  The Gaseous Form option can similarly be turning yourself into (non-damaging) living flame that can move around.  Maybe more visible than normal gaseous form.

Answer (score 5):

## Way of the Ascendant Dragon

Fitzban's Treasury of Dragons introduced the Way of the Ascendant Dragon. The description of the school reads:

> The fundamental teaching of this tradition holds that by emulating dragons, a monk becomes a more integrated part of the world and its magic.

In particular, a monk who chooses this Way gains the following benefits that relate to your goal:

> **Draconic Strike**. When you damage a target with an unarmed strike, you can change the damage type to acid, cold, **fire**, lightning, or poison.

> **Breath of the Dragon**
> *3rd-Level Way of the Ascendant Dragon Feature*
>
> You can channel destructive waves of energy, like those created by the dragons you emulate. When you take the Attack action on your turn, you can replace one of the attacks with an exhalation of draconic energy in either a 20-foot cone or a 30-foot line that is 5 feet wide (your choice). Choose a damage type: acid, cold, **fire**, lightning, or poison. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw against your ki save DC, taking damage of the chosen type equal to two rolls of your Martial Arts die on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.

> **Aspect of the Wyrm**
> *11th-Level Way of the Ascendant Dragon Feature
>
> **Resistance**. Choose a damage type when you activate this aura: acid, cold, **fire**, lightning, or poison. You and your allies within the aura have resistance to that damage.

> **Ascendant Aspect**
> *17th-Level Way of the Ascendant Dragon Feature
> **Explosive Fury**. When you activate your Aspect of the Wyrm, draconic fury explodes from you. Choose any number of creatures you can see in your aura. Each of those creatures must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw against your ki save DC or take 3d10 acid, cold, **fire**, lightning, or poison damage (your choice).

These features are based around dragons but the ability to use fire relates directly to your needs.

Further, given the fact that red dragons are connected to fire, it would be easy to connect the dots and say that dragons are an aspect of a god of fire and it chooses that form too represent itself.

Or you could just "reskin" the Way and, instead of draconic breath, simply be a cone of fire that erupts from your hands or chest (Iron man style).